# Show treeview items connected with lines?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, treeviewitem

Is there a way to make the treeview show lines connecting items when we expand them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'd have to replace TreeViewItem control template to achieve that. Look at [this thread on MSDN (via archive.org)](https://web.archive.org/web/20121214055941/http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/30cb182c-9419-40bd-946e-87971515fb95/) there should be all information you need.